# How to set response header in Jayson RPC Server implemented as a express middleware

Tags: express, json-rpc

The server implementation as a express middleware is straightforward.

```
const rpcServer = jayson.server({
  add: function(args, callback) {
    callback(null, args[0] + args[1]);
  }
});
express().post('/rpc', function(req, res, next) {

        console.log("Req Headers:" + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
        const context = { headers: req.headers };
        
        rpcServer.call(req.body, context, function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                if(err instanceof Error) return next(err);
                res.status(400);
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }
            
            const { GT_CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env;
            const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', GT_CLIENT_SECRET)
            .update(JSON.stringify(result))
            .digest('hex');
            
            if(result) {
                res.send(result);
            } else {
                res.status(204);
                res.send('');
            }
        });
    })
```

Regarding the request headers docs say *You can provide an optional context object to JSON-RPC method handlers. This can be used to give extra data to a handler such as request headers, authentication tokens, and so on.*